# Salesforce Flow: Account Name Missing in Email Notification but not in Debug

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a Record Triggered Flow to send an email containing basic information about a newly created Quote (aka Proposal) to a specific email address. After the Quote(Proposal) is created, I receive the email with all the information I need about the Quote(Proposal) **except for the Account Name that is associated with the Quote**. When I run the debug, the Account Name shows up.

EmailBodyNewQuote text template:

*Dear Team,
A Quote with the following information was created:
Account Name: {!GetAccountName.Name}
Proposal Name: {!$Record.Name}
Proposal Number: {!$Record.Id}
Thanks.*
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

I have checked the flow logic and ensured that the GetAccountName step is firing correctly.
I have verified that the {!GetAccountName.Name} merge field is spelled correctly and is referencing the appropriate field.
I have checked the security settings on the Account object and the flow to ensure that the flow has the necessary permissions to access the Account Name field.
I am still unable to resolve the issue. Can anyone please help me understand why the Account Name is not populating in the email notification, but is available in the debug log?

Salesforce Flow API Version 60.[image]
I have attached a screenshot of the flow for your reference.

Any help would be appreciated!

Addendum:
If I add to the Flow a Custom Error Message, in which the message is a text variable with the value `{!GetAccountName.Name}`, the debug shows the Account Name but the error message itself does not show the  Account name to the user.

Comment: I would always start investigating by considering permission and sharing issues, unless your flow runs in System Mode without Sharing.

Comment: The Flow is Record-Triggered so it will always run in system mode without sharing. Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5

Comment: Fair enough; I should have spent the time to peer closely at the image - one of the reasons it is better to provide words to support screenshots (when they are required) - adding the text also allows people using screen readers to answer or benefit from the question and answer later.

Comment: When i wrote the question I did not know that the way the Flow runs could be important, so I did not mentioned it. After your comment, I've research more and share the result.  I have edited the Question and now it mention "Record Triggered Flow" .Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used {!$Record.Opportunity.Account.Name} in the Text Template.
Do not use {!GetAccountName.Name}.
Thanks to all!

Comment: accept your own answer to provide a service to the community